# Google Calendar API Quickstart Project No results returned

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

Hi I visited the android quickstart guide for the Google Calendar API

so I made the quickstart example after this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android)

and when I run the application this happens:
[result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esNi8.jpg)

Does that mean that it worked vor what?

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working fine.
This is happening based on this part of the code:

```
@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
    mProgress.hide();
    if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
         mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
        } else {
          output.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Google Calendar API:");
          mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
        }
  }
```

You are getting the `"No results returned."` message because it wasn't able to fetch anything. Go to your `calendar.google.com`, add some dummy events, then make another call again. It should be able to return the events and show it on your screen.